# Scheduler Failures in Kubernetes Airflow Cluster

Tags: airflow, airflow-k8s

After setting up Airflow in a Kubernetes cluster with the Kubernetes executor using Airflow Helm Chart and disabling the triggerer, all services are operational. However, I noticed that the scheduler intermittently goes down, even when there is no significant workload. Upon inspecting the scheduler logs, I consistently encounter the following error. This issue persists despite occasional periods of minimal or no load on the system.

```
[2024-03-13T10:30:06.718+0000] {process_utils.py:79} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=387, status='terminated', started='10:30:02') (387) terminated with exit code None
[2024-03-13T10:30:06.771+0000] {process_utils.py:79} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=113, status='terminated', exitcode=0, started='10:29:15') (113) terminated with exit code 0
[2024-03-13T10:30:06.775+0000] {kubernetes_executor.py:713} INFO - Shutting down Kubernetes executor
[2024-03-13T10:30:06.776+0000] {scheduler_job_runner.py:868} ERROR - Exception when executing Executor.end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 845, in _execute
    self._run_scheduler_loop()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 979, in _run_scheduler_loop
    num_queued_tis = self._do_scheduling(session)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 1061, in _do_scheduling
    callback_tuples = self._schedule_all_dag_runs(guard, dag_runs, session)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/retries.py", line 91, in wrapped_function
    for attempt in run_with_db_retries(max_retries=retries, logger=logger, **retry_kwargs):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 347, in __iter__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 314, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/retries.py", line 100, in wrapped_function
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 1380, in _schedule_all_dag_runs
    callback_tuples = [(run, self._schedule_dag_run(run, session=session)) for run in dag_runs]
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 1380, in <listcomp>
    callback_tuples = [(run, self._schedule_dag_run(run, session=session)) for run in dag_runs]
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 1404, in _schedule_dag_run
    dag_model = with_row_locks(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2850, in one_or_none
    return self._iter().one_or_none()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2916, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1720, in execute
    result = compile_state_cls.orm_setup_cursor_result(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 349, in orm_setup_cursor_result
    return loading.instances(result, querycontext)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 69, in instances
    *[
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 70, in <listcomp>
    query_entity.row_processor(context, cursor)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 2631, in row_processor
    _instance = loading._instance_processor(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 796, in _instance_processor
    prop.create_row_processor(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 658, in create_row_processor
    strat.create_row_processor(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 2540, in create_row_processor
    _instance = loading._instance_processor(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 796, in _instance_processor
    prop.create_row_processor(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 653, in create_row_processor
    loader = self._get_context_loader(context, path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 611, in _get_context_loader
    search_path = path[self]
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/path_registry.py", line 486, in __getitem__
    return PropRegistry(self, entity)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/path_registry.py", line 327, in __init__
    insp = inspection.inspect(parent[-1])
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/path_registry.py", line 480, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, entity):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 251, in _exit_gracefully
    sys.exit(os.EX_OK)
SystemExit: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 866, in _execute
    self.job.executor.end()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 716, in end
    self._flush_task_queue()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 668, in _flush_task_queue
    self.log.debug("Executor shutting down, task_queue approximate size=%d", self.task_queue.qsize())
  File "<string>", line 2, in qsize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 834, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[2024-03-13T10:30:06.801+0000] {process_utils.py:131} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to group 113. PIDs of all processes in the group: []
[2024-03-13T10:30:06.801+0000] {process_utils.py:86} INFO - Sending the signal Signals.SIGTERM to group 113
[2024-03-13T10:30:06.802+0000] {process_utils.py:100} INFO - Sending the signal Signals.SIGTERM to process 113 as process group is missing.
[2024-03-13T10:30:06.802+0000] {scheduler_job_runner.py:874} INFO - Exited execute loop
WARNING: MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```

what should I do to fix above issue? Could the scheduler's intermittent shutdowns be attributed to insufficient system memory?

Airflow Version : 2.7.1